# View y_true of batch in Keras Callback during training

Tags: machine-learning, keras, callback, loss-function

I am attempting to implement a custom loss functoin in Keras. It requires that I compute the sum of the inverse class frequencies for each `y in B`

It is the `1/epsilon(...)`  portion of the below function

[image]

The functoin is from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07413) - Page 7

*Note: I most definitely could be misinterpreting what the paper is describing to do. Please let me know if I am*

I am currently trying to use a Keras Callback and the `on_batch_start/end` methods to try and determine the class frequency of the input batch (which means accessing `y_true` of the batch input), but am having little luck.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

**Edit:** By "little luck" I mean I cannot find a way to access the `y_true` of an individual batch during training. Example: `batch_size = 64`, `train_features.shape == (50000, 120, 20)`, I cannot find a way to access the `y_true` of an individual batch during training. I can access the keras model from `on_batch_start/end` (`self.model`), but I cannot find a way to access the actual `y_true` of the batch, size 64.

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import Callback


class FreqReWeight(Callback):
  """
  Update learning rate by batch label frequency distribution -- for use with LDAM loss
  """

  def __init__(self, C):
    self.C = C

  def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
    self.model.custom_val = 0

  def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    print('batch index', batch)
    print('Model being trained', self.model)

    # how can one access the y_true of the batch?
```

**LDAM Loss Function**

*z<sub>j</sub> = "the j-th output of the model for the j-th class"*

[image: LDAM loss function]

**EDIT2**

*Loss Function - for testing when loss is called*

```py
def LDAM(C):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        print('shape', y_true.shape)  # only prints each epoch, not each batch
        return K.mean(y_pred) + C  # NOT LDAM, just dummy for testing purposes

    return loss
```

*Preparing Data, Compiling Model & Training*

```py
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, 10)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, 10)
    m = 64  # batch_size

    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                     input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(10))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=LDAM(1), optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])

    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
              batch_size=m,
              validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
              callbacks=[FreqReWeight(1)])
```

Comment: could you please report the code of your callbacks? why did you say you have little luck (code errors or bad results)?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani - By "little luck" I mean I cannot find a way to access the y_true of an individual batch. Example: batch_size = 64, train_features.shape = (50000, 120, 20), I cannot find a way to access the `y_true` of an individual batch during training. I can access the keras model from `on_batch_start/end` (`self.model`), but I cannot find a way to access the actual `y_true` of the batch, size 64.

Comment: Report your code of loss/callbacks if it's possible

Comment: @MarcoCerliani - I've added a snpipet of the Callback. Specifically, I want to be able to access the `y_true` while inside `on_batch_end/start`. I do not currently have any logic defined in the loss function. I will edit the post to include the defintion of the loss function from the paper.

Comment: I think you need simply a custom loss function which is optimized batch-wise

Comment: @MarcoCerliani - I would agree. How do I set it to optimize batch-wise?

Comment: every loss is optimized by default batch-wise... the loss you see at the end of the epoch is the mean of all the losses calculated in each batch

Comment: @MarcoCerliani - I will need to double check that. When I add a printout to the loss function, it's only called every epoch, and not every batch. I've added the code to show data import, model compilation, and the call to `model.fit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Ended up asking a more specific question regarding this.

Answer to both can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61859671/is-it-possible-to-update-the-learning-rate-each-batch-based-on-batch-label-y)

Comment: can you share your Keras implementation of LDAM loss?